# How do single thread with non-blocking work?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, nonblocking

If a single thread calls a non-blocking function, how the non-blocking function is processed? A new thread is created and the returned(but not ended) non-blocking is executed in that thread? I mean the case of general non-blocking function, not specific to I/O.

And please let me know the pros and cons of multi threading with blocking call and single thread with non-blocking call.

Comment: If you specify the nonblocking function you are talking about, you might even be able to locate its sourcecode to look at.

Comment: Re, "..._general_ non-blocking function..." You haven't named any operating system, any library, any programming language. That is _extremely_ "general." I don't believe that there is any "general" answer at such an abstract level.

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two ways this works:

1. The function makes as much forward progress as it can and then returns an indication that it cannot make any more forward progress without blocking. With this model, the application has to do something else later to continue/finish the operation.
2. The function somehow arranges for the work to be done later. This might mean creating a new thread in the application. It might mean arranging for the operating system to do something else later. In this case, the application may have a way to check on the status of the operation or the operation's code may have some way to notify the application when it has made progress.